# Is it possible to re-link a binary with a different compatible shared library or load two libraries with the same name

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I'll use windows as an example but I'm interested in hearing if there is a solution for the analogous problem in linux.

I have an app (called `app.exe`) linked against two libraries (`shared.dll` and `second.dll`). The library `second.dll` happens to be linked against **a third** library (also called `shared.dll`) which happens to have the same name as that which is linked with `app.exe`, but is not a binary compatible version. In fact, they are two non-compatible versions of the same software library.

So the dependency graph is:

```
         app.exe
        /       \
  shared.dll  second.dll 
     (v1)         \
                shared.dll
                   (v2)
```

`app.exe` first loads `shared.dll` and then `second.dll` which in turn tries to load a library named `shared.dll`. Windows now thinks this library is already loaded but `second.dll` won't find the entry-points it depends on and will fail.

Assuming I **don't have access to any of the source codes** can I rename one of the `shared.dll`s to `shared_other.dll` and somehow "re-link" `second.dll` with `shared_other.dll`. Is there any other way to solve the conflict?

P.S `app.exe` is MATLAB, `second.dll` is the Python Interpreter library, and the `shared.dll`s are different versions of the HDF5 library - the one that MATLAB uses and the other that is used by the Keras pre-compiled wheel.

Comment: It depends on how the shared library is linked and loaded in both cases.   Generally speaking,without modifying source of `app.exe` or `second.dll` (e.g. to dynamically load the library at a specified path) it is not possible to resolve this.  Your best bet would be to seek builds of both the app and the library that use (i.e. are linked against and, at run time, load) the same version of the shared DLL.

Comment: I think that linker scripts on Linux have a potential here. It was many years since I last saw a linker script, but there is some chance it can help you on linux. Also maybe elfsh can help https://github.com/thorkill/eresi/wiki/TheELFsh (never used it, so I  can't guarantee a thing)

Comment: Another option I would explore, is to open the library dynamically and access its functions through a wrapper that will use a handle to the dll. On Linux this should be dlopen and dlsym